# Black Screen on my rasberry pie, no greenlight, only just installed OS and havent actually used the pi, why won't it display anything on screen?

Tags: pi-4

Essentially, I've got a new raspberry pi-4 today, I set it up and then downloaded the Raspberry Pi Full OS. Once it had downloaded it displayed a message saying OS installed I clicked ok, then black screen, and nothing since. I have unplugged it and every time it will boot to the rainbow screen then welcome to your raspberry pi picture or something then a black screen with a dash in the top left then a black screen. I have taken SD out and put it back in. Initially, the greenlight is on then flashes green then goes red. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it's not a `pie`

Comment: Have you seen the sticky on the official Raspberry Pi forum site? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151

Comment: `the greenlight is on then flashes green then goes red` ... there is no greenlight that goes red on a pi-4 ... there's a green light and a red light ... the red light should always be on ... the green light essentially shows "disk activity" in default setup. Did you use the official raspberry pi imager? did you set up a user?

Comment: *Once it had downloaded it displayed a message saying OS installed I clicked ok, then black screen* ... did you not take the sd card and place it in the raspberry pi?

Comment: See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)
although your Pi is probably booting. The Pi4 fails to work on some monitors - try another.